# Javascript: Get the browser's selected microphone name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microphone, getusermedia

I'm trying to build a function to get the browser's selected microphone name via Javascript. Like if we have several microphones in the system and the browser have one selected, I need to know his name to use it in other functions.

I tryed the getUserMedia method but i can't figure how to get the microphone name with this. And, as I read in some articles there are some incompatibilities with google chrome.

Is there any other way to get this info?

Comment: Have you already looked at `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`? Explained here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices It's only supported on Google Chrome and Firefox though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()**

  mediaDevice.label

---

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(function(devices) {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {
    console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
            " id = " + device.deviceId);
  });
})
```

Supported by Chrome 45, Firefox 39

---

- **MediaStreamTrack.getSources()**

> *Deprecated*

```
MediaStreamTrack.label
```

---

```
MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sourceInfos) {
  for (var i = 0; i != sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
    var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
    console.log(sourceInfo.id, sourceInfo.label);
  }
});
```

> **Deprecated in Chrome 45, removed in Chrome 47.**

---

***getUserMedia MUST be invoked before 'enumerateDevices' or 'getSources' methods***

---

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply! Both solutions working well and is a good push for what I need. However it's hard to know the microphone which the browser are using, since they have always the same order no matter which one is selected by default in browser.

Comment: "Some OSes like OSX have a "virtual" default device, which usually has the word "default" in its label (which is only available during use or if user has granted persistent permissions), but not every OS does this, and I don't know of any other way to detect a default."  @jib http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264487/web-audio-api-input-from-specific-microphone

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main Language. I'll try to explain it better:

I have this microphone selected by default in browser: http://s9.postimg.org/igwc1yrfz/mic.png

Now I need to know via Javascript the name/ID of this Microphone. The one that is selected as default in browser.

The reason I need this is to send that name or id to a service, because I'll have another application that will need to use another microphone. And in this application need to exclude the microphone being used in the browser.

Comment: So maybe I need to create a function that allows the user to select the microphone and, based on his decision, send it to the service.

Comment: pretty much as shown here https://deeppai.com/2014/01/28/device-enumeration-and-media-source-selection/

Comment: `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` does ***not*** work in Firefox. Please remove mention of Firefox from that part of the answer, or better, don't suggest it at all, as it is deprecated.