# Testing microphone in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am testing my microphone in HTML + JS. It all works well with the record and play. Now I want to add a dropdown-list of microphone devices connected to the computer/device. This part is getting trickier as I do not know if I have to use a library or is there an easier way to do this?

Basically a dropdown list to select the input microphone device and then proceed further to record.

Please be free to alter the code below, it is from github.

EDIT: After following the link posted by the user, I integrated that in my code. Now the microphone devices shows up. But the problem is that it does not show the name of the microphone device. Why is that?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            const record = document.getElementById("record");
            const visualizer = document.getElementById("visualizer");
            const stop = document.getElementById("stop");
            const audio = document.getElementById("audio");

            const canvasCtx = visualizer.getContext("2d");
            let chunks = [];

            navigator.mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia({
                    audio: true
                })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    visualize(stream);

                    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                        chunks.push(e.data);
                    };

                    mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
                        const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
                            type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus"
                        });
                        audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        audio.play();

                        // clear recorded audio
                        chunks = [];
                    };

                    record.onclick = function () {
                        mediaRecorder.start();

                        visualizer.style.display = "block";
                        audio.style.display = "none";
                        stop.style.display = "block";
                        record.style.display = "none";

                        stop.disabled = false;
                        record.disabled = true;
                    };

                    stop.onclick = function () {
                        mediaRecorder.stop();

                        visualizer.style.display = "none";
                        audio.style.display = "block";
                        stop.style.display = "none";
                        record.style.display = "block";

                        stop.disabled = true;
                        record.disabled = false;
                    };
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    alert("There was a problem accessing your microphone.");
                });

            function visualize(stream) {
                const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
                const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

                const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
                analyser.fftSize = 2048;
                const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
                const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

                source.connect(analyser);

                draw();

                function draw() {
                    WIDTH = visualizer.width;
                    HEIGHT = visualizer.height;

                    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

                    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

                    canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                    canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                    canvasCtx.lineWidth = 1;
                    canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "#4287f5";

                    canvasCtx.beginPath();

                    let sliceWidth = (WIDTH * 1.0) / bufferLength;
                    let x = 0;

                    for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
                        let v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
                        let y = (v * HEIGHT) / 2;

                        if (i === 0) {
                            canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
                        } else {
                            canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
                        }

                        x += sliceWidth;
                    }

                    canvasCtx.lineTo(visualizer.width, visualizer.height / 2);
                    canvasCtx.stroke();
                }
            }
        });



        const audioInputSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
        const selectors = [audioInputSelect];

        function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
            // Handles being called several times to update labels. Preserve values.
            const values = selectors.map(select => select.value);
            selectors.forEach(select => {
                while (select.firstChild) {
                    select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
                }
            });
            for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
                const deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
                const option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
                if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
                    option.text = deviceInfo.label || `microphone ${audioInputSelect.length + 1}`;
                    audioInputSelect.appendChild(option);
                }
            }
            selectors.forEach((select, selectorIndex) => {
                if (Array.prototype.slice.call(select.childNodes).some(n => n.value === values[selectorIndex])) {
                    select.value = values[selectorIndex];
                }
            });
        }


        function handleError(error) {
            console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
        }

        function start() {
            // Second call to getUserMedia() with changed device may cause error, so we need to release stream before changing device
            if (window.stream) {
                stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
            }

            const audioSource = audioInputSelect.value;

            const constraints = {
                audio: { deviceId: audioSource ? { exact: audioSource } : undefined }
            };

        }

        audioInputSelect.onchange = start;


        navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
            .then(gotDevices)
            .then(start)
            .catch(handleError);
```

```css
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            color: #606c76;
            font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial",
                sans-serif;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        h1,
        p,
        div {
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 3.6rem;
        }

        #record {
            background-color: #1b89f0;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #visualizer {
            display: none;
            margin: 10px 0;
            height: 60px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #stop {
            background-color: #e90a0a;
            display: none;
            border: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #audio {
            display: none;
            margin: 10px 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* Desktop Styles */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
            body {
                max-width: 600px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <main>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="record">Record</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
        </div>
        <p>
            <label for="audioSource">Audio input source: </label>
            <select id="audioSource"></select>
        </p>
        <canvas id="visualizer"></canvas>
        <audio id="audio" controls="true"></audio>
    </main>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Audio Api input from specific microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264487/web-audio-api-input-from-specific-microphone)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bomzj/beap6n2g/

Comment: @ErfanBahramali thank you yes that worked and I updated my question but still there are issues.